# Looking for redirect to specific domains only

Tags: url-rewriting, iis-7, redirect, http-redirect

I am new IIS, but came up in a situation where not all of our clients use ssl on their website but there are a few who does. Hence the problem here is that after enabling redirection, when it redirects to ssl enabled pages, it works well but gives ssl warning on non ssl websites.

I want to add some redirect rules which:
1. Redirects with https on the domains only which I allow.
2. Redirects with http only for the sites not in allowed list.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Rastu.

Comment: Add conditions to check host names of the incoming requests. Tons of examples on Google.

Answer (score 0):

As lex says, we could use url rewrite's condition to achieve your requirement.You could put this url rewrite rule insdie the web site.

Notice: Condition's HTTP_HOST should set the domain whcih doesn't enable the SSL.

```
        <rules>
           <rule name="HTTP to HTTPS on different SSL Port" enabled="true" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="(.*)" ignoreCase="true"  negate="false" />
             <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="true">
                <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="off" />
                <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainwithoutusingSSL.com$" negate="true"/>
           <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^www.domainwithoutusingSSL2.com$" negate="true"/>
            </conditions>
            <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}{REQUEST_URI}" appendQueryString="true" />
        </rule>
```